# Поиск глубины дерева в Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, дерево

Мне нужно создать дерево, и найти сумму которая ровняется умножению каждой вершины дерева на глубину.У меня есть два класса `Node` и `Main`. В классе `Node` я объявляю основные функции для роботы с деревом, в классе `Main` функцией `readChildren` заполняю дерево, но не знаю как найти глубину самого дерева (дерево не двоичное)

```
public class Main {
static Node<Integer> theNode;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter root value: ");
    Node<Integer> root = new Node<>(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
    System.out.println("Enter childs with coma separator: ");
    System.out.println("For root element: ");

    readChildren(root);

}

public static void readChildren(Node<Integer> child) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter children for " + child.getData() + ": ");
    String children = reader.readLine();
    if (children.isEmpty())
        return;
    String charr[] = children.split(",");
    int i = 0;
    for (String ch : charr) {
        child.addChild(Integer.parseInt(ch));
        readChildren(child.getChildren().get(i++));
    }
}

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node<T> {
private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
private Node<T> parent = null;
private T data = null;

public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = parent;
}

public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
    // parent.addChild(this);
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void addChild(T data) {
    Node<T> child = new Node<T>(data);
    child.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
    child.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

public int getChildrenCount() {
    return this.getChildren().size();
}

public T getData() {
    return this.data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public boolean isRoot() {
    return (this.parent == null);
}

public boolean isLeaf() {
    if (this.children.size() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void removeParent() {
    this.parent = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Самая удобная логика при работе с деревьями - рекурсия. Глубина ищется как максимальная глубина веток нода +1 (текущий нод). Т.е. берешь все ветки нода перебором, вызывваешь для них этот же метод и возвращаешь максимальную глубину + 1. Проверка останова - нет детей, тогда просто возвращаешь 1.

Comment: можешь пример если не сложно, а то не знаю как в етом коде его реализовать

Comment: р**а**бота, р**а**вняется

Answer (score 1):

написал свою функцию для поиска глубины, может кому-то понадобится

```
public static int getTreeHightRecurs(Node<Integer> root) {
    int deep = 0;
    for (Node<Integer> node :root.getChildren())
        deep = Integer.max(deep, getTreeHightRecurs(node));
    return deep+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код не рабочий, я для примера привожу

```
    public int getTreeHight(){
        return getTreeHightRecurs(root);
    }

    private int getTreeHightRecurs(Node root){
        if (root.getChildrens()=null) return 1;
        List<Integer>  hihgts = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Node node:root.getChildrens()){
            int hight = getTreeHightRecurs(node);
            hihgts.add(hight);
        }
        return Collections.max(hihgts);
    }
```

С java8 Stream вообще будет 2 строки, только я пока не готов его написать